# iPad Subviews appear to have portrait orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have an app where I only support landscape orientation, it works great in ios6 but in ios5 some of the subviews appear to have portait coordinates and sizes. I have put

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
      interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

everywhere I can imagine, yet these views seem stuck to portait, my width param seems to be the height and vice versa.

The main view for the appear appears to be correct but some subviews seem wrong especially ones that calculate their position and size from other elements, I am afraid to swap the dimensions since this would break ios6 and i dont want to do any conditional code if I can avoid it.

Has anyone seen this? I read a few other questions but they seemed to deal with handling the rotation, but in my case i am not rotating.

Basically in my viewDidLoad for my navigation controller

my frame has:

```
2013-01-10 17:14:29.445 EdwardsSync[29070:c07] Width:: 768.000000
2013-01-10 17:14:29.445 EdwardsSync[29070:c07] Height:: 1024.000000
```

even though it appears in landscape. This is true of frame and bounds.

interesting if I wait till viewDidAppear the coordinates are correct.

is there a way to tell my app the orientation sooner?

Comment: have you looked at the frame and bounds in viewWillAppear?

Comment: yes they are correct there, but that isnt ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also go into the xib in Interface Builder and adjust the dimensions of the view. Properties under view select Orientation Landscape.  It's under Simulated Metrics. Also Size Metrics you can specify 1024 x 768, etc.

In Build Settings remove the Portrait Views if you want.

Comment: this works great in ios6 and its what i have been doing, my issue seems to be in ios5.

Comment: make sure autoresize subviews is not checked either. That could be what's messing it up.

Comment: also use autolayout is a feature only specific to iOS 6.0, if it's checked in 5.0 you'll have errors.

Comment: I think with XCode 4.5 or 4.5.2 it started being included. can't remember.

Comment: no not using auto layout. the app runs, just some views seem stuck in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

The support for rotation in UIViewController changed in iOS 6.  Look at the Handling View Rotations section of this page:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

In particular, check the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` methods.  The comments in the header file are quite helpful.

Also, what orientations have you defined in your app’s Info.plist file?

Comment: I don't understand - are the problem views displaying in portrait?  Or do you mean just the dimensions are swapped?

Comment: It seems as if the width and height are swapped for some subviews.

Comment: Are you getting the dimensions from the subview's frame or bounds?

Answer (score 0):

set the autoresizingMask for your view

```
yourview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

use this to get height and width

```
CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)
CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)
```